# mp4 player is not working in FF while using load-balancing

Tags: firefox, coldfusion, load-balancing, coldfusion-9

I am using load-balancing in my application hosted in ColdFusion 9 application server and am trying to play an mp4 video. I am displaying the video directly in the browser by clicking an anchor tag. Its working fine in IE, but does not work in Firefox. Firefox displays some junk characters like squares and question marks. There is no video or error message. However, when I run the same application without load-balancing its working fine in FF. Is the issue is due to the load balancing or do I need to set a MIME type?

Note: I am using FF 23.0

Comment: "displaying some encoded characters": What do you mean by that? Is there video, or an error message? Do the response headers returned via direct connections look the same as the ones passing through the load balancer? Most importantly: Does your Firefox build actually [support mp4/h264 video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility)? Or do you use a flash fallback or something like that?

Comment: Its displaying some junk characters like squares ans question marks. There is no video or error message. I am trying to play mp4 video.

Comment: "Do the response headers returned via direct connections look the same as the ones passing through the load balancer": How can I check the response headers?

Comment: First of all: Please edit your question with any additional details you provide instead of "hiding" them in comments. Tools such as The Firefox Web Console or Wireshark may be used to log request/response information or even full streams.

Comment: You're displaying the video directly, not in a `<video>` tag, right? That would indicate that the load balancer messes up the MIME in the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Yes nmaier, I am displaying the video directly in the browser by clicking an anchor tag. So what Content-Type should I add to the header?

Comment: MIME, see links in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18589349/484441

Comment: Now I am using 
   `<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="videoFile.mp4">`
   `<cfcontent type="video/mp4" file="file path">`
Hope it will work on load balancing server. I will let you know after being tested from QA.

Comment: No, its not working in load balance server. Is there any other way to fix it out?

Comment: As I said earlier: There is no way to actually diagnose this without you providing more details. The MIME type stuff is a common mistake, hence I just guessed there.

Comment: There is a simple .cfm page where the below code is written  to prompt the user to download the mp4 video file.`<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="videoFile.mp4"> <cfcontent type="video/mp4" file="file path">` This code is working fine under normal server configuration. But when the same server is configure using load balance it throws some garbage value (random encrypted text) instead of download pop up in Firefox. The same function works fine in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with HTML 5  tag with flash fallback support. The code is `

```
            <source src="https://#CGI.SERVER_NAME#/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="https://#CGI.SERVER_NAME#/video.webm" type="video/webm">

            <!--- Flash player code to play video in HTML5 non support browser --->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"  width="1000" height="600">
                <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'https://#CGI.SERVER_NAME#/video.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}">
            </object>
        </video>`
```

Also I added MIME types in httpd.conf file of Apache server. The MIME types are,

AddType video/ogg .ogv

AddType video/mp4 .mp4

AddType video/webm .webm

Now its working fine.